# How can I get classes from "protected" JAR file?

Tags: java, decompile

I'm trying to get classes from JAR file / actually running JVM machine but:

When I'm trying to open JAR file using for example 7Zip I dont see any classes. After unzip Manifest file is empty too.

When I'm trying to "dump" classes from running JVM machine, I got "very funny" named - empty classes (not really empty, but contains info like "gtfo" etc..)

JD-Gui showed nothing - just nothing.

Around month ago, when I tried to open it using 7Zip, there was classes with same name, and custom extension.

What should I do, and what tools do You recommend for actions like this?

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qhfEXu-ITQLW1mi55hMqnHmWt9BM5ur3/view

EDIT: Every decompiler I tested show info like this:

> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "net/minecraft/client/main/Main",
> "\u0000extends throws try goto 8 \n 9 * package * + finally return
> static * " float abstract | transient \n synchronized catch =
> strictfp transient static extends while final long ! 0 throws & \n %
> double 4 this if const \n interface ' ^ ~ do 1 ] % ? throws super
> long", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;", false)

Comment: Those "very funny" names are probably the actual names of the classfiles in the JAR

Comment: But "extracted" class names depends on method how I get them. When dumping classes  I got those funny names, but when tried JD-Gui or other "extractors?" I got fragments from poems or sth like that: https://i.imgur.com/sL9W6g3.png

Comment: JD-Gui is really unreliable. Trust your zip extractor. Also, I'd recommend checking out the Krakatau disassembler: https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau

Comment: I got those output when trying to use decompiler and no result in output directory. https://pastebin.com/EGMbeUeN

Diassembler give the same error.

Comment: It appears that your Jar file is malformed then. If you upload it, then maybe I can take a look later.

Comment: Thanks You for activity in my thread. Here is link for file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hronFiXCqeS0uCkjMKmWoev9RyEQy8Wu/view

Comment: Your link does not exist anymore, but could you try using https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf to see if it can automatically handle the malformed input?

Comment: Oh, link is broken - I cant fix it now. I will test it later (in 3 days / or I will fix link)

Comment: If it doesn't work, feel free to open a bug report in Recaf's repo. I'd like to support intentionally malformed jars like this.

Comment: It doesnt work in my case. Classes with those "bushes" in name is still there with same name(?), there are classes with "test.a.class", "test.b.class", a bit of classes without name etc..
Fixed link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qhfEXu-ITQLW1mi55hMqnHmWt9BM5ur3/view

Answer (score 3):

The obfuscator probably used the '\u0000' "exploit".
This character is known as NUL terminator and its used for terminate the length of a character string in C/C++.
All renamed classes will contain that character, this will confuse tools like 7Zip, WinRar etc..

Quick explanation:

=======

Original file names:

1. Main.class
2. Main2.class
3. Main3.class

Renamed file names:

1. Main.class\u0000.class -> 7Zip -> *Main.class* (\u0000 is the string end so the other characters will be not displayed)
2. Main.class\u0000**2**.class -> 7Zip -> *Main.class*
3. Main.class\u0000**3**.class -> 7Zip -> *Main.class*

=======

Try to use https://github.com/TerriblePanda/JByteMod-Reborn or https://github.com/GraxCode/threadtear to decompile your jar.

Probable obfuscator used: https://paramorphism.dev/

Comment: wow, in my opinion it can be this one. I will test it in ~3days

Comment: Anyway, can you provide the jar?

Comment: Link was in comments, but added it and it's in post now

Comment: I can confirm my theory. The classes starts with \u0000.